Error while doing ESM in QuantumEspresso/7.3.1
I am trying to do charged surface calculations using Quantum Espresso/7.3.1. I have a copper slab and am trying to adsorb CO2 molecule on one of the adsorption sites. Later, I will compare the adsorption energies in the presence and absence of charge. But when I am trying to do ESM with the "bc3" boundary condition, I get the following error:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine esm_stress_ewg_bc2 (1):
     FIXME: expm used but not defined
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

I could not figure out the source of this error. I am using all the necessary tags required for it. Below is my input file for reference.
&CONTROL
calculation='relax',
outdir='/home/tanay11/scratch/qe/Cu_charge_test/outdir',
prefix='ad_site_4',
pseudo_dir='/home/tanay11/scratch/qe/Cu_charge_test/pseudo',
verbosity='high',
restart_mode='from_scratch',
tstress = .true.
tprnfor = .true.
etot_conv_thr = 1.0D-4,
forc_conv_thr =1.0D-3,
nstep = 1000

/
&SYSTEM
ibrav=0,
celldm(1)=14.4913458890d0,
nat=57,
ntyp=3,
ecutwfc=40,
ecutrho=400,
starting_magnetization(1)=0.5,
nspin = 2,
occupations='smearing',
smearing='mp',
degauss=0.005d0,
nosym = .true.,
vdw_corr = 'dft-d3'
tot_charge=-1
assume_isolated='esm',
esm_bc='bc3'
nbnd = 1000
/
&ELECTRONS
conv_thr=1d-06,
mixing_beta=0.1d0,
diagonalization='cg'
mixing_mode = 'local-TF'
electron_maxstep = 1000
/

&IONS
ion_dynamics = 'bfgs' ,

/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
C 12.010700d0 C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF
Cu 63.546000d0 Cu.pbe-kjpaw.UPF
O 15.999400d0 O.pbe-kjpaw.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.0176338515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.0828568515d0
Cu   0.0000000000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   1.0000000000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   1.0000000000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.1480788515d0
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.1111110000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.4444440000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.2222220000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.5555560000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.8888890000d0   0.7777780000d0   0.2133008515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.2222220000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.1111110000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.4444440000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   0.7777780000d0   0.8888890000d0   0.2785228515d0
Cu   1.0000000000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.0000000000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu  -0.0000000000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.3333330000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.0000000000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.3333330000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.3437458515d0
Cu   0.6666670000d0   0.6666670000d0   0.3437458515d0
 C   0.4444900000d0   0.5555790000d0   0.4275776723d0
 O   0.4445380000d0   0.5556060000d0   0.4645330137d0
 O   0.4444440000d0   0.5555560000d0   0.3906208515d0

K_POINTS {automatic}
 2 2 1 0 0 0

CELL_PARAMETERS {alat}
1.000000000000d0  0.000000000000d0  0.000000000000d0
-0.500000000000d0  0.866025384398d0  0.000000000000d0
 0.000000000000d0  0.000000000000d0  4.172894533344d0


Please, add the information in code block instead as an image.

@Camps Done thanks
